# A big and long question about the deeds of the heart

Tags: quran, hadith, fiqh, sunnah, islamic-philosophy

I have the most special question to make that if honorable contributors like mehdi saif and others would reply, I would thank them in eternity. I want to understand the relationship between the deeds of the heart and exterior deeds. Who weighs more on the scale the deeds of the heart like love, hope, hatred linking of the heart or doing large quantity of deeds like Charles Darwin that has become a cause for billions of people to disbelieve  god and increase sins and prophet Muhammad that has become a cause for billions of people to believe God and increase their good deeds and decrease bad deeds. I asked a shaikh who is more sinful Charles Darwin or the dajjal. He replied the dajjal. This proves that the deeds of heart are far heavier than any external good or bad deed we can make. Because there have been prophets that haven't been followed by a single individual and they still have the iman grade of a prophet. For this reason I ask and want to know who is more sinful majooj yajooj or the dajjal? Because that would prove that the deeds of heart are far heavier than any exterior deeds because majooj yajooj will harm very few creatures at the end times unlike Charles Darwin that has become a cause for billions of people to completely disbelieve god ,has become a cause for all those wars like first and second world war and has become a cause for all those wars between the secularists and religious people in the middle East and beyond. He has also become a cause for all those women that dress inappropriately in the Arab world and beyond. He has become a cause for all those ideologies like faschism  and communism that greatly inhibit Islam. He has also become a cause for the suffering of all those muslims in the Arab world and beyond. The fact that the dajjal is more sinful than Charles Darwin proves that the deeds of the heart are far heavier than any other exterior deeds we can make. This is why I asked to rank sinfulness of Charles Darwin, dajjal, Adolph Hitler, Joseph Stalin and majooj yajooj. Because that would prove my theory about the deeds of heart. Please give me a long answer about the deeds of heart and their relationship with other deeds.

Comment: My word---that's a wall of text.  Would it be possible to [edit] to highlight the question (and delete the noise)?

Answer (score 0):

Allah will account us for everything we do according to our intentions(niyyah), influencing people is also the same Prophet (pbuh) said "Scholar who gives a ruling about a matter with good intentions get two rewards if it is true, gets one reward if it's not true." So even influencing people Allah looks into our hearts, it's not the deed itself will cause us to go to Paradise but it's the mercy of Allah. In the same way for causing harm is not only about the act itself, it's about the intentions. That proves heart is more important than exterior acts.

As for ranking the names you've given it's not possible nor reasonable for us to do that kind of ranking. Only Allah knows the heart of the people, we only have tiny knowledge. So don't bother trying to rank people but if you want to learn the mistakes and the bad they caused to society, do it with intention of analyzing situations not people itself.

Additionally, with all due respect, please don't make Islam so complicated. It's a simple religion, go out there and do things with good intentions by expecting its reward only from Allah, and ask forgiveness for the bad things you did intentionally and unintentionally. Islam is a practical religion let's keep it that way :)

Allah knows the best !